# Display Document Library Folder contents on a different Sharepoint 2007 Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, webpart

What I want to do seems incredibly simple, but I am getting nowhere quickly searching and reading about this.

I need to list some policy documents on a Sharepoint page on our corporate intranet.  This is in web application http://intranet  The documents are stored in a folder in a document library in our HR Team Site - that's in http://teams/sites/HR.

There seem to be a variety of methods for displaying the content of the folder on pages within the same site collection or site (e.g. Content Query Web Part, List View Web Part, Data View Web Part), but automatically displaying this in a different site collection seems very difficult, without spending a lot of money on a third party web app, or spending many hours writing one myself.

Am I missing something here?  I thought Sharepoint was about leveraging your content and data across the enterprise.

Comment: There are web parts that can access document libraries on other web applications and site collections - e.g. My Sharepoint Sites which displays documents I have recently edited on any site I specify.  So this isn't technically impossible.